# What kind of type have the range in for loop?

Tags: ios, swift, range

When we write the following:

```
for i in 1...10 {
//do stuff
}
```

I want know what type have the range `1...10` to use it in function call for example:

```
myFunc(1...10)
```

Comment: use NSarray for "for in loop"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint after defining `let range = 1..<10`, you will see that it's actually not a `Range` structure, but rater a `CountableRange` (or `CountableClosedRange` for 0...10)

Docs: [CountableRange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countablerange), [CountableClosedRange](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/countableclosedrange)

Functions:

```
func printRange(range: CountableRange<Int>) {
    for i in range { print ("\(i)") }
}

func printRange(range: CountableClosedRange<Int>) {
    for i in range { print ("\(i)") }
}
```

Usage:

```
let range = 1..<10
printRange(range: range)

let closedRange = 1...10
printRange(range: closedRange)
```

**Generic function:**

Since both structs conform to `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, you can implement only one function like this:

```
func printRange<R>(range: R) where R: RandomAccessCollection {
    for i in range { print ("\(i)") }
}
```

[This article](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/09/swift-3-ranges/) about ranges in Swift 3 may also be useful.

Comment: *Challenge:* Define a function that accepts both `1...10` and `1..<10` as argument :)

Comment: @MartinR: Accepted ;)

Comment: That's what I meant – I learned about it here: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-users/Week-of-Mon-20161010/003654.html.

Comment: Doing great, guys! I was following the challenge quest and came to the point that both things conform to `RandomAccessCollection`, just didn't know to write the syntax of generic type functions. Thanks a lot for the lesson.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in 1...10 {
      print(i)
}
```

**Output** : 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

your this loop is run 10 time if you start it with 0 then your loop run 11 time . hope you clear with start with 0 and 1 what is different

and ya as you ask that myfunc(1...10) that means

```
Range(1..<11)
  - startIndex : 1
  - endIndex : 11
```

Answer (score 0):

These are called Ranges (see here - https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/range)

So myfunc would be declared as

`func myfunc(range: Range)`

Comment: This function won't accept 0...1 range since it is `CountableClosedRange`, not `Range`