# How to get a String array of years like monthSymbols in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I want to get an array of Strings years like monthSymbols.

example: [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020,... 2100]

I do that with the month of year:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
let monthComponents = formatter.monthSymbols
```

but I can't do the same with the years. any help?

Comment: Just use DateFormatter with dateFormat "yyyy" and map an array of dates containing the first day of each year and get a string representation for them

Comment: @LeoDabus Like in my answer? :)

Comment: @rmaddy yes but you could simplify the way you are creating the dates. no need to specify day and month using flatMap `(2017...2100).flatMap{ DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: $0).date`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think such a thing exists.  An arbitrary list of years can't really be handled in the same way as a specific list of month names.

`let years = (2017...2100).map { String($0) }` is probably the cleanest way to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I just ```let currentDate = Date()

        let calendar = Calendar.current

        let currentYear = calendar.component(.year, from: currentDate)

        let years = (currentYear...2100).map { String($0) }```

Comment: Works for Swift 4.0

Answer (score 2):

If you want a simple mapping of the numbers from 2017-2100 as strings, the other answer works. But if you want a properly localized list of years for the user's given locale, then you need to do a bit more.

Here's an extension to `DateFormatter` that lets you specify a year range:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    func years<R: RandomAccessCollection>(_ range: R) -> [String] where R.Iterator.Element == Int {
        setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy")
        var comps = DateComponents(month: 1, day: 1)
        var res = [String]()
        for y in range {
            comps.year = y
            if let date = calendar.date(from: comps) {
                res.append(string(from: date))
            }
        }

        return res
    }
}
```

And here is a little test code:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
print(df.years(2017...2100))
```

This code makes use of the user's locale and the user's calendar.

You really see a difference when the user's locale is Arabic or any other locale that uses digits other than 0-9.

And thanks to the suggestion by Leo Dabus, this can be shortened to:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    func years<R: RandomAccessCollection>(_ range: R) -> [String] where R.Iterator.Element == Int {
        setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy")
        let res = range.flatMap { DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: $0).date }.flatMap { string(from: $0) }

        return res
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus - Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: you are welcome `func years(_ range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> [String]  {
        setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy")
        return Array(range.lowerBound...range.upperBound).flatMap{ DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: $0).date }.flatMap{ string(from: $0) }
    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus So now it doesn't work with an open range. That's why mine is slightly more complicated. It works with open ranges, closed ranges, and even arrays. I'm still trying to figure out how to limit it to just collections of `Int`.

Comment: @LeoDabus That's temporary until I figure out how to indicate that the `range` parameter is specifically of type `Int`. At the moment you can actually pass a collection of any type to the `years` method.

Comment: I don't think Array is a good idea. Why would you allow to repeat an element or change the years order ?

Comment: @LeoDabus See http://stackoverflow.com/a/40124040/1226963 I want to support both open and closed ranges with one method.

Comment: you can constrain the elements of your collection to Int as follow `func years<R: RandomAccessCollection>(_ range: R) -> [String] where R.Iterator.Element == Int {
        setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("yyyy")
        return range.flatMap{ DateComponents(calendar: .current, year: $0).date }.flatMap{ string(from: $0) }
    }`

Comment: @LeoDabus Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: why create a var? `return range.flatMap { DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: $0).date }.flatMap { string(from: $0) }` btw res will never change

Comment: @LeoDabus Debugging.

Comment: BTW you can add more constrains if needed `R.Iterator.Element == Int, R.Index == Int, R.IndexDistance == Int`